# brew installed software (keg-only) which includes /usr/local/Cellar/*/share/man/ - No manual entry for readline

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew

I installed the keg-only readline

```
> brew info readline
readline: stable 7.0.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Library for command-line editing
https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0 (45 files, 2M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-11-22 at 22:40:10
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1 (46 files, 2M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-12-03 at 22:44:53
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/readline.rb
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

macOS provides the BSD libedit library, which shadows libreadline.
In order to prevent conflicts when programs look for libreadline we are
defaulting this GNU Readline installation to keg-only.


Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include
```

This package installs manpages:

```
> brew ls -v readline | grep man
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/info/rluserman.info
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/man/man3/history.3
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/man/man3/readline.3
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/readline/fileman.c
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/readline/manexamp.c
```

I can't see the manual. I get `No manual entry for readline`.

Howto view the manual with `man readline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-M` option for `man` allows you to specify a path. The exact command you're looking for is:

```
man -M 3 /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/man/man3/readline.3
```

Note that the number after the `-M` specifies the "`man` page section", which is the last character in the file path. For example, I have two versions of `sshd` installed and I read can both their `man` pages with the following commands:

```
man -M 8 /usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8
man -M 8 /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/7.3p1/share/man/man8/sshd.8
```

I'm curious why `brew` didn't symlink `readline`, since `brew`'s `readline` is the only one installed - presumably past versions (I'm on Sierra) of macOS *did* have `readline`? I'd tend to be conservative here, and honour `brew`'s decision as far as possible - just in case Apple decide to install `readline` again with a future OS upgrade. That being said, you could manually symlink `readline`:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1/share/man/man3/readline.3 /usr/local/share/man/man3/readline.3
```

The risk with this is that - if Apple do install `readline` in the future - you'll end up with Apple's `readline` in your $PATH (and not `brew`'s, since it's keg-only and hasn't been linked), but `brew`'s `readline` will occur first in your $MANPATH, before the `man` page for Apple's `readline`.